# Word for an accident that is lucky or fortunate?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

A few days back, I happened to check the meaning of the word [**mishap**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mishap) in Merriam Webster's online dictionary. It says that a **mishap** is

> "an **unfortunate** accident"

And in Oxford's dictionary [**'mishap'**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mishap), it is described as:

> "an **unlucky** accident".

So, my questions is if there is any word to describe a ***lucky or fortunate*** accident?

Because an accident by itself is a bad event, isn't it? (Accident: An unfortunate incident that happens unexpectedly and unintentionally, typically resulting in damage or injury.)

So what do you call an accident that's lucky or fortunate?

Comment: Anything unintentional is accidental. Walking into the shop at 35 High Street when you meant to go into 33 High Street is an accident; it may be fortunate, unfortunate or neutral, depending on what happens to you in the shop at 35 High Street.

Comment: Google Books claims to have over 13,000 written instances of [by a lucky accident](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22by+a+lucky+accident%22), so there are plenty of examples for you to learn from.

Comment: @AndyT Can I ask you something? Why your comment/explanation is so open ended? Why there is no conformity in the explanation. I mean, I said already that merriam websters describes it as an UNLUCKY or UNFORTUNATE accident then there is no question of you saying that 'hey, I don't know what happens when you go in that shop'.

Comment: " I happened to check the meaning of the word 'mishap'." Did you check the meaning of "accident"?

Comment: @Looper - What's wrong with my comment being open ended? I wasn't answering your question (which is why it's a comment not an answer), I was debunking your assertion that "accident by itself is a bad event". Very possibly there are language issues here: you don't appear to be a native speaker and how I'm interpreting your sentences is not necessarily how you intended them.

Comment: Only *one* sense of the word *accident* means "bad." Merriam-Webster, which you reference, provides two *other* senses, and the first sense does not mean bad. If you're only using the "bad" sense, then it would seem a contradiction to have a "lucky bad event."

Comment: @Kris lol! while checking meaning of Mishap, I checked meaning of accident as well.

Comment: @AndyT please don't shout. Secondly, don't throw native speaker jibe on me. Only thing you can do is downvote. You so pissed?

Comment: What did that say, and why wasn't that adequate?

Comment: @Looper - When did I shout? As to the native speaker part - I wasn't blaming you (I'm sorry if I thought that), I was implying that if my comment didn't make sense to you that we should explore ways of rephrasing your question. I'll be more explicit here: is your question "are the words *unlucky* and *unfortunate* redundant here?" or is it "is there a word a lucky or fortunate accident?"? I hadn't downvoted, or voted to close, though now I've taken the time to think this through I have now voted to close as "unclear what you're asking" until you've answered my question here.

Comment: @Looper - Oh, and no, I'm not angry or annoyed. I would like to remind you of the [Be Nice policy](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) - I do my best to stick to it, and I hope you do too.

Answer (score 3):

**Serendipity:**

> **1]** an aptitude for making desirable discoveries by accident **2]** accidental discovery, or an instance of this **3]** good fortune; luck [(Dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/serendipity?s=t)

> 1754: coined by Horace Walpole, suggested by The Three Princes of Serendip, the title of a fairy tale in which the heroes ‘were always making discoveries, by accidents and sagacity, of things they were not in quest of’ [(Oxford Languages)](https://www.google.com/search?q=serendipity)

Comment: I was excepting this word to pop-up. But can you confirm that Serendipity is a fortunate accident? Because an experiment which went out of control, resulted into something useful is called serendipity. So, something unfortunate occurred, which resulted into something useful.

Comment: http://mentalfloss.com/article/53646/24-important-scientific-discoveries-happened-accident

Answer (score 1):

[Serendipity](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/serendipity):  "The art of happy accidents"

Comment: There is a Disney song by this name that was played on Mickey Mouse Club and to promote the movie "Flubber", but, alas, there does not appear to be a recording of it online anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> A blessing in disguise.

-An apparent misfortune that eventually has good results.

Answer (score 0):

a **stroke of luck**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stroke+of+luck)  idiom

> **An unexpected fortunate occurrence**. Meeting my favorite celebrity at
>   the airport was certainly a stroke of luck that wouldn't have happened
>   if I'd arrived five minutes later. I worked very hard on the script,
>   but getting to pitch it to the producer in the elevator was just a
>   stroke of luck.

or

**happy accident** also in TDF - an idiom

> A mistake or unplanned event that results in a beneficial outcome or
>   pleasant surprise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you answer is differs the intension of the question I have asked. I am more interested to know: Is there anything called Lucky or Fortunate accident because by the definition itself accident means bad event. Stroke of luck can not be assumed as an accident. Stroke of luck is a stroke of luck and not an accident.

Comment: me thinks me did not coin it!

Answer (score -1):

I would consider either of the following as possible solutions:

> **turn of good fortune** (seizing on your mention of "unfortunate"): https://www.thefreedictionary.com/good+fortune

... or ...

> **fluke** (third definition): https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fluke
>
> 1. A chance occurrence: That spring snowstorm was a total fluke.
> 2. *Games* An accidentally good or successful stroke in billiards or pool.

I do admit that "fluke" is more neutral and may need another adjective to project is as favorable.